# Division by $\sqrt{n}$ in CLT and linear transformations

Tags: statistics, linear-transformations, statistical-inference, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

I recently tried to solve two problems$^1$, and do not understand their solution. In both cases, the problem was that I did not divide some expression by $\sqrt n$.

First problem:

> Imagine that students bring a mean of 4 framed photographs to
>   campus, with a standard deviation of 2 photographs.If students are
>   randomly assigned to live in quad-style dorm rooms (four students per
>   room), what is the mean and standard deviation of the distribution of
>   total number of framed photographs per dorm room?

According to the lecture notes, when transforming a random variable $X$ by a function $Y=bX+a,$ $\bar{Y}=b\bar{X}+a$ and $\sigma_Y=|b|\sigma_X.$ Therefore, I wrote that the new mean is 16 and the new standard deviation is 8. But the solution says this: $SD[T]=\sqrt{n} \cdot \operatorname{SD}[X]=\sqrt{4}\cdot n=4$!!!   I do not understand how it is possible given the facts about linear transformations. And if this is not enough, there is also a problem in the same worksheet:

> Suppose that a set of exam scores has a mean of 80 with a standard
>   deviation of 6. Calculate the mean and standard deviation of the new,
>   transformed distributions of exam scores if each score is increased by
>   20%.

And the solution says: $y=1.2x$, $s_y=|1.2|s_x=7.2$, which confirms my original understanding of linear transformations.

Second problem:

> A user experience researcher wants to know if all users prefer one
>   website layout (Layout A) over another (Layout B). He samples n = 64
>   customers and asks them which layout they prefer. He finds a sample
>   proportion of $\widehat p = 0.68$ prefer Layout A, and wants to know if this is
>   evidence that there is a preference in the population of all users,
>   using $\alpha = .01$.

And according to the solution:

> the central limit theorem tells us that the distribution of sample
>   proportions will: 
>     have a mean of μM = π = .50 have a standard
>   deviation of σM = √(π*(1-π) / n) = √(.5*.5/64) = .0625

But on the very same document, it says:

> For any population with a mean μ and standard deviation σ, the
>   distribution of sample means from that population for sample size n
>   will: 1. have a mean of μ written E[M], E[X̅], μM, μX̅ 2. have a
>   standard deviation of σ / √n.

And since the users are binomially distributed, the standard deviation of the sample should be $\sqrt{nπ(1-π)}=4$, and dividing by $\sqrt{n}$ we get .5, not .0625.

If anyone can explain to me what I am missing here I would be extremely grateful!

$^1$ From the contents of Psych 10 at Stanford. Specifically, the first problem is number 17 from [practice problem set 3](http://web.stanford.edu/class/psych10/resources/P10_PracticePS_W3_Solutions.pdf), and the second problem is from slide 34 in the [1/30/17 slides](http://web.stanford.edu/class/psych10/schedule/P10_W4L1).

Comment: For $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, \pi),$ we have $\sigma_X^2 = Var(X) = n\pi(1-\pi)$. If $M = \hat \pi = X/n,$ then $Var(M) = \pi(1-\pi)/n$ and $\sigma_M = SD(M) = \sqrt{\pi(1-\pi)/n}.$ See my Answer for $SD(\bar X).$

Comment: For the dorm case, the expected number of photos per student is $4$ and the variance is $2^2$, meaning  the expected number of photos per dorm is $4+4+4+4=16$ and the variance is $2^2+2^2+2^2+2^2$, making the standard deviation per dorm $\sqrt{2^2+2^2+2^2+2^2}=4$ not $2+2+2+2=8$.  Each student is independent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first two cases, you are dealing with an average $\bar X$ if $n$ normal
observations, $X_i \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu, \sigma).$

Thus, $E(X_i) = \mu$ and $Var(X_i) = \sigma^2.$ Then to find $E(\bar X),$
we proceed as follows.

$$E(\bar X) = E\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = 
\frac{1}{n}E\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)
=\frac{1}{n}\left(E(X_1) + E(X_2) + \cdots + E(X_n)\right)\\ = \frac{1}{n}n\mu = \mu,$$
where we have used  $E(aY) = aE(Y)$, where $a = 1/n$, in the second step and an extended
version of $E(X + Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$ to get the last term in the first line.

The proof that $Var(\bar X) = \sigma^2/n$ uses $Var(aY) = a^2Var(Y)$, again for $a = 1/n$, which is how we get $n$ in the denominator.

[It seems you have a mistake in your formula for variances above, where you are summarizing lecture notes: For *standard deviations*, $SD(bY) = \sigma_{bY} =|b|\sigma_Y =|b|SD(Y)$, but *not for variances.*]

Also, because the $X_i$ are *independent,* the variance of their sum is the sum of their variances. Putting it all together, we have

$$Var(\bar X) = Var\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right) = 
\frac{1}{n^2}Var\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right)  
=\frac{1}{n^2}\left(Var(X_1) + \cdots + Var(X_n)\right) \\= \frac{1}{n^2}n\sigma^2 = \sigma^2/n,$$

Then finally, taking square roots, we have $SD(\bar X) = \sigma/\sqrt{n},$
which is the equation that puzzled you. If you look around in your textbook
you can probably find a similar discussion somewhere.